# Excel adding more conditions in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I believed the condtions written will be quite long and i am not really good in writing this long formula
There are 6 columns i've used which is D ,E, M, N, O, P
Sample data:

```
D3=123456(Changing variable as it can be 12345, 12345A,123456A)  
E3=1  
M3=31  
N3=_  
O3=00  
P3=0
```

The formula are design based on this Column D field(the variable changes is in this field) let say
if length of D3 = 6 then (the current formula i've done)

```
=IF(LEN(D3)=6,CONCATENATE(M3,D3,N3,O3,E3),CONCATENATE(M3,D3,O3,E3))
```

The outcome for this will be 31123456_001, if let say the D variable is changed to 123456A( the else
in the formula i've shown as no concatenate N3)
then the outcome will be 31123456A001.

I have added in column p, so that i can use it to concatenate to the format that i need.
There are a few more conditions i need to add in,
Which is
**1. If the D3= 12345, the format outcome will be 31012345_001 (concatenate M3,P3,D3,N3,O3,E3)**  
**2. If the D= 12345A, the format outcome will be 31012345A001 (concatenate M3,P3,D3,O3,E3)**  
**3. Data for the column D3 field, 12345*A*, the *A* alphabet can be in A-Z.**

These are the list of all conditions and outcome that i required in a formula.

```
1.  D3 = 123456 then the outcome will be 31123456_001  
2.  D3 = 123456A then outcome will be 31123456A001  
3.  D3 = 12345 then outcome will be 31012345_001  
4.  D3 = 12345A then outcome will be 31012345A001
```

Additional info:
These are just format as it can be any numbers combinations, the last letter alphabet can be A-Z

```
D3 = 123456
D3 = 123456A
D3 = 12345
D3 = 12345A
```

Comment: what is the priority for these new conditions? i.e do they belong around the already existing formula or somewhere inside it?

Comment: yes, they must added into the existing formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answers, it's

```
=IF(AND(LEN(D3)>=6,ISNUMBER(RIGHT(D3,1)*1)),M3&D3&N3&O3&E3,IF(AND(LEN(D3)<6,ISNUMBER(RIGHT(D3,1)*1)),M3&P3&D3&N3&O3&E3,IF(AND(LEN(D3)=6,ISTEXT(RIGHT(D3,1))),M3&P3&D3&O3&E3,M3&D3&O3&E3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I couldn't quite catch all the conditions and outcomes, here is an example of how your formula could look:

```
    =IF(LEN(D3)=5,Outcome_1_Concatenation,IF(LEN(D3)=7,Outcome_2_Concatenation,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D3,1))),Outcome_3_Concatenation,Outcome_4_Concatenation)))

Outcome_1_Concatenation => replace with formula when LEN = 5
Outcome_2_Concatenation => replace with formula when LEN = 7
Outcome_3_Concatenation => replace with formula when LEN = 6 and all are numbers
Outcome_4_Concatenation => replace with formula when LEN = 6 and last is character
```

If you give all examples in a `condition => outcome` list, I would be glad to help further.

Comment: Just revised my question once again, hopefully you understand.

Comment: I understood yet the outcomes weren't in formulas so you'll just need to add those as described below formula.

Comment: yeah, it's quite similar to what i needed, but the thing is how am i going to write this part, LEN = 6 and last is character, or any suggestion to rewrite all the formulas?

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(D3,1)*1),M3&D3&N3&O3&E3,M3&D3&O3&E3)

Comment: it's quite similar to the formula above i written, but it doesn't fulfilled the conditions 3 and 4 because i can't concatenate the 0 in p column using this formula.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at creating a lookup table range with 3 options for lengths of 5,6,7.

I named my lookup table range "Length".

First setup this lookup table like this:

5 |

```
=CONCATENATE(M$3,P$3,D$3,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D3,1))),N3,""),O$3,E$3)
```

6 |

```
=CONCATENATE(M$3,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D$3,1))),"",P$3),D$3,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D3,1))),N$3,""),O$3,E$3)
```

7 |

```
=CONCATENATE(M$3,D$3,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(D$3,1))),N$3,""),O$3,E$3)
```

For any D3 value, it is checking if that last character is a letter, and if not it will insert N3, otherwise it leaves it out.

Also, for any 6 character value, it checks if the last character is a letter, and if so, it will insert P3, otherwise it leaves it out.

Then, your output formula should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEN(D3),Length,2,FALSE)
```

This makes it clean and simple.

[image]

Comment: yes, i can do that, this is indeed quite a good suggestion, but i have a pool of data, this will cause a lot of confusion. i prefer all the conditions in one formula.

Answer (score 1):

This is your formula plus the added conditions 1 and 2:

`=IF(D3=12345,CONCATENATE(M3,P3,D3,N3,O3,E3),IF(D3="12345A",CONCATENATE(M3,P3,D3,O3,E3),IF(LEN(D3)=6,CONCATENATE(M3,D3,N3,O3,E3),CONCATENATE(M3,D3,O3,E3)))`

If you want a more generalized version you can check if D3 is a number, the length of it, if D3 ends with a letter, and replace the nested ifs according to your needs

Comment: i am trying your formula right now, will let you know later.

Comment: hey david, how to check D3 ends with a letter and the meanwhile checking with all length? can you give me some guide?